# In Android Kotlin, what's the right way to pass a onclick event into a viewholder?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclick, android-viewholder

Is there any difference in these two ways?
I've been using the seond way and it works so far, yet I found the first way upon reading tutorial articles.

1st:

```
class FlowersAdapter(private val onClick: (Flower) -> Unit) :
ListAdapter<Flower, FlowersAdapter.FlowerViewHolder>(FlowerDiffCallback) {

/* ViewHolder for Flower, takes in the inflated view and the onClick behavior. */
class FlowerViewHolder(itemView: View, val onClick: (Flower) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val flowerTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flower_text)
    private val flowerImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flower_image)
    private var currentFlower: Flower? = null

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            currentFlower?.let {
                onClick(it)
            }
        }
    }

    /* Bind flower name and image. */
    fun bind(flower: Flower) {
        currentFlower = flower

        flowerTextView.text = flower.name
        if (flower.image != null) {
            flowerImageView.setImageResource(flower.image)
        } else {
            flowerImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rose)
        }
    }
}
```

}

[First way of writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFhSk.png)

2nd:

```
class FlowerViewHolder(itemView: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val flowerTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flower_text)
    private val flowerImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flower_image)
    private var currentFlower: Flower? = null

    /* Bind flower name and image. */
    fun bind(flower: Flower) {
        currentFlower = flower

        flowerTextView.text = flower.name
        if (flower.image != null) {
            flowerImageView.setImageResource(flower.image)
        } else {
            flowerImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rose)
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onClick(flower)
        }
    }
}
```

[Second way of writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUoFa.png)

Appreicate your time and effort in telling me the differences.

Answer (score 1):

From the perceptive of separation of concern, all the `clickListeners` are supposed to be handled in the `Activity` or `Fragment` and `Adapters` are meant just to wrap around the items, in your case `Flower` and present them in a way which can be used by the `RecyclerView` to display on the screen.

With that being said, the core logic of clickListeners is to be moved out of the `bind` method into the activity/fragment and that's precisely whats the firstMethod is all about. Matter of fact, I haven't noticed any performance improvement by employing the FirstMethod over the second one yet I insist on using FirstOne because its more of code organizing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helps to know it's for separation of concern.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I feel like the adapter should know nothing about click listeners or any details about the `ViewHolder`; so I wouldn't pass the callback through the adapter.

I like passing the callback to my `ViewHolder` but instead of mapping into the `init` block I do it on the `onBind` hook from the adapter where I receive the view as a parameter. Also, I pass or update the `ViewHolder`s directly into my `Adapter`s. And then have some generic functions to compute whether the data-set has changed or not.

If you do it like this, you have the benefit that you may build 1 generic adapter and use it elsewhere without really minding how many different types of `ViewHolder` you may have to implement later on as it is completely agnostic.

#### TLDR;

So based on what you've provided us I would use the good things of both approaches. Binding the callback into the `bind` hook and passing the callback through the constructor of the `ViewHolder`

Comment: wow that's a good idea I haven't thought about combinding the two, plus generic adapter sounds like much less boilerplate codes